# Distinct values using PHP

Tags: php, foreach, array-unique

I want to get only the distinct values from `$pjt`. I have tried the below code:

```php
$unique_pjtdata = array_unique($pjt);
foreach($unique_pjtdata as $val) {
     echo $val;
}
```

I am getting an HTTP Error 500 after trying this code.

Comment: which type of value in `$pjt` ? Also enable error reporting to know errors.

Comment: When you get a 500 error, check the PHP error log for the reason.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I have declared $pjt as array

Answer (score 2):

Use array_unique().

Example:

```
$pjt = array(1, 2, 2, 3);
$array = array_unique($pjt);
```

and if you still get error then you need to enable error reporting to know error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`array_flip()`** to switch the keys and values in the array therefore forcing duplicate values to overwrite into a unique set of keys:

```
$b = ["test1", "test2", "test1", "test3"];
$b = array_flip($b);

print_r( $b );

//output
Array
(
  [test1] => 2
  [test2] => 1
  [test3] => 3
)
```

You can then extract the keys using **`array_keys()`**:

```
$b = array_keys($b);

print_r($b)

// output
Array
(
  [0] => test1
  [1] => test2
  [2] => test3
)
```